# How do I use an existing email server with WAMP?

Tags: email, smtp, wamp

I have a WAMP server installed on my computer.  I am using it to develop my website.  A few  features of the site will involve sending mail.  I have an actual web server with email.  Is there a way to configure WAMP to use my existing email server?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the P in your WAMP is PHP, you want to set up email for PHP, not WAMP. There is tons of documentation on how to set this up: http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,31302,70969 You configure your mail settings in your php.ini file.